# visitors/day Statistics incorrect?

Tags: discussion

I would assume, that

- most users of this page are Tor users.
- many only log in if they want to say something. (Because TBB does not store passwords by default.)

Other notable things:

- TBB clears cookies.
- We share Tor exit relays.

Couldn't this result in stackexchange's statistic algorithm getting things wrong?

Not that I care about statistics, I am happy with this forum as is, but I've read that stackexchange will delete the forum if there is too little activity.

Answer (score 3):

Stack exchange sites are mostly judged based on a few criteria:

- Questions per day
- % answered questions
- User base ("avid" users vs. total users)
- Answer ratio
- Visits per day

The only metric the user of Tor could potentially affect is visits per day, but I'm not sure that equates to "unique visits per day" so it may not be even that.

You can see where this community currently stands on its [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56447/tor).

Comment: We could add a question, asking everyone to add a comment every day that they login.

Comment: Note, those stats are _heavily_ cached, so use them only as a general reference point and not an indication of how the site has done in the last few weeks.